# APEX Salesforce last Login Date/time to Date

Tags: date, datetime, salesforce, apex

The below class will push the logindate into the custom field. You can use a formula to convert it from date/time to date. Then setup a scheduler to run the apex to keep the last login date up to date.

```
public void ResetlastLogin_Update(List<User> oldUsers, List<User> newUsers) {

System.debug('ResetlastLogin_Update: entering trigger');

List<Id> idsToUpdate = new List<Id>();

for (integer i=0; i<newUsers.size(); i++) {
  User newVals = newUsers[i];
  User oldVals = oldUsers[i];

  if (newVals.lastlogindate != oldVals.lastlogindate__c) {
          idsToUpdate.add(newVals.Id);
  }
}
System.debug('Ids to Update: ' + idsToUpdate.size());

if (idsToUpdate.size() > 0) {

  List<User> usersToUpdate = [SELECT Id, lastlogindate, lastlogindate__c FROM User WHERE Id IN :idsToUpdate];
  for (User u : usersToUpdate) {

  if (u.lastlogindate__c == NULL ) {

     u.lastlogindate__c = u.lastlogindate ;
    }
   }
  update usersToUpdate;

}

System.debug('ResetlastLogin_Update_Update: exiting trigger');
```

}

Comment: Really it would be best if there was a way to make this after update so that when the user logs in it automatically pushes the new login date into the custom field. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/execute-an-action-run-a-trigger-every-time-a-user-logs-in-to-salesforce. The act of logging in doesn't count as update of user record (for example lastmodifieddate doesn't change) which means that workflows & formulas are out of the question too.

You'll have to use batch apex to query that data or maybe consume a login history report (via Analytics API)...

---

As for your question. To convert from DateTime to Date you can use [`date()` or `dateGMT()`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_Datetime_instance_methods.htm).

```
DateTime dt = System.now();
Date d = dt.date();
System.debug(dt + '  ->  ' + d);
System.assertEquals(System.today(), d);

2014-01-14 18:44:14  ->  2014-01-14 00:00:00
```